# Prime number checker is not working past 23

Tags: python

I have a code here, I wonder why it's not working past number 23?
I mean it's not checking appropriately

```
def prime_checker(number):
  divlist = []
  for i in range(2, number):
    remainder = number%i
    divlist += str(remainder)
        
  if "0" not in divlist:
    print(f"{number} is prime")
  else:
    print(f"{number} is not prime")
  print(divlist)

n = int(input("Check this number: "))
prime_checker(number=n)
```

[image: checking 23]

Comment: Beside the point, but why are you using strings instead of ints? **Edit**: Oops it's actually not beside the point, it's the problem. I'll write an answer.

Comment: What is the point of keeping `divlist`?  The moment you find a divisor with a remainder of zero, *you have your answer* - none of the previous remainders matter, none of the remaining remainders are worth calculating.

Comment: use `.append`, using `+=` added `"1"` and `"0"`, and because you had a `"0"`, your code said it wasn't a prime

Comment: But, there are a lot more ways to go about finding primes, importantly both more efficient and **more logical**. Like what jasonharper has said. But also, you only need to divide up until sqrt(number), and you can skip over multiples of numbers you've already tried

Answer (score 1):

`list += x` is the same as `list.extend(x)`, which means if you get a multi-digit `remainder`, *its characters* (i.e. strings of length 1) will be added to the list *individually*. You should use `list.append(x)` instead, and for that matter, don't convert to str unnecessarily.

```
def prime_checker(number):
    divlist = []
    for i in range(2, number):
        remainder = number % i
        divlist.append(remainder)

    if 0 not in divlist:
        print(f"{number} is prime")
    else:
        print(f"{number} is not prime")
    print(divlist)
```

```
>>> prime_checker(23)
23 is prime
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 5, 3, 1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

the main error is :

```
divlist += str(remainder)
```

you should replace it with:

```
divlist.append(remainder)
```

You should keep track of the reminders as a list of numbers:
do not convert them to strings, and use append(..) to grow the list.
So also replace "0" by 0 in the check.

Here is corrected code working for 23:

```
def prime_checker(number):
  divlist = []
  for i in range(2, number):
    remainder = number%i
    divlist.append (remainder)
        
  if 0 not in divlist:
    print(f"{number} is prime")
  else:
    print(f"{number} is not prime")
  print(divlist)

n = int(input("Check this number: "))
prime_checker(number=n)
```

Output is:

```
Check this number: 23
23 is prime
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 5, 3, 1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Please note that this solution is working, but not optimal. You will probably find some optimal and faster way to do it already here in Stackoverflow Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

`divlist += str(remainder)`
with:
`divlist.append(remainder)`
If you use `+= str(remainder)`, `str(remainder)` will be separated into single digits before added into the `divlist`

Comment: If you're switching to ints there, you also need to switch lower down: `if 0 not in divlist`

Comment: @wjandrea I think so too. He better to do that

Answer (score -1):

declare a count variable which increase when the reminder is zero for each iteration, at the end of program check weather it is greater than 2 or not, if greater number is not prime else number is prime.